# How add ControlTemplate to Content?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, controltemplate

I have ControlTemplate (XAML).
I need in code behid add ControlTemplate to TabItem.Content.

```
var tabItem = new TabItem
      {
      DataContext = listDesk,
      Header = headerText,
      Content = ???

      };
```

XAML

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTabItemContentTemplate" TargetType="controls:TabItem">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="wwwwww"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I use SL4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confusing concepts. Instead of setting the `Content`, which is data, set the `Template`, which is the visual representation of the control:

```
var tabItem = new TabItem
      {
      DataContext = listDesk,
      Header = headerText,
      Template = this.FindResource("MyTabitemContentTemplate") as ControlTemplate

      };
```

Moreover, chances are there is no reason to do this in code. You could be doing it entirely in XAML.

Comment: @denis: it was a typo, now fixed.